# Oracle sqlplus execute sql script from command line while passing parameters to the sql script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have one script `script.sql` which I want to execute from command line using oracle and passing it two parameters, as shown below

```
sqlplus user/pass @ script.sql my_parameter1_value my_parameter2_value
```

What should it be in `script.sql` in order to be able to run it with the parameter values?

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be prepared looking at oracle blogs:

https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables#2_7

For the question above, the solution would be to create a `script.sql` like this:

```
DEFINE START_VALUE = &1;
DEFINE STOP_VALUE = &2;

SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE
 value BETWEN &&START_VALUE AND &&STOP_VALUE;
```

Comment: "... looking at oracle blocks." What are these **blocks**? I'd like to look at them too.

Comment: @Littlefoot  I wanted to refer to oracle blogs. I already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run a script that would return all orders raised during the last seven days. Here's how...

the script

```
SELECT * FROM orders_detail WHERE order_date BETWEEN '&1' AND '&2';
EXIT;
```

the command

sqlplus ot/Orcl1234@xepdb1 @"/opt/oracle/oradata/Custom Scripts/orders_between_dates.sql" $(date +%d-%b-%Y -d '-7 days') $(date +%d-%b-%Y)

Hope that helps someone. Luck.